# Отделяется ли оборот запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

На одном сообществе мне попался такой вопрос. Предложение следующее: "Как и на прошлых соревнованиях(,) победили нижегородцы". Мне кажется, что запятая тут не нужна, потому что оборот стоит в начале предложения. Но хотелось бы услышать мнение специалистов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всегда выделяется оборот, который начинается с *как и*.